# let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ \ a_i > 0 $ be convergent then prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ , \ a_i > 0 $  be  convergent.

I need to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$
is convergent.

How should I prove it? Where should I start?